# Image uploading in images folder issue in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to upload JPG file to a folder I have created in my project.

The image does not get saved in the images folder.  It displays my image when I upload but the image itself is not present in images folder.

Here is the code i am using:

```
private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Initialize variables
    string sSavePath;
    string sThumbExtension;
    int intThumbWidth;
    int intThumbHeight;

    // Set constant values
    sSavePath = "images/";
    sThumbExtension = "_thumb";
    intThumbWidth = 160;
    intThumbHeight = 120;

    // If file field isn’t empty
    if (filUpload.PostedFile != null)
    {
        // Check file size (mustn’t be 0)
        HttpPostedFile myFile = filUpload.PostedFile;
        int nFileLen = myFile.ContentLength;
        if (nFileLen == 0)
        {
            lblOutput.Text = "No file was uploaded.";
            return;
        }

        // Check file extension (must be JPG)
        if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(myFile.FileName).ToLower() != ".jpg")
        {
            lblOutput.Text = "The file must have an extension of JPG";
            return;
        }

        // Read file into a data stream
        byte[] myData = new Byte[nFileLen];
        myFile.InputStream.Read(myData,0,nFileLen);

        // Make sure a duplicate file doesn’t exist.  If it does, keep on appending an 
        // incremental numeric until it is unique
        string sFilename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(myFile.FileName);
        int file_append = 0;
        while (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(sSavePath + sFilename)))
        {
            file_append++;
            sFilename = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(myFile.FileName)
                             + file_append.ToString() + ".jpg";
        }

        // Save the stream to disk
        System.IO.FileStream newFile
                = new System.IO.FileStream(Server.MapPath(sSavePath + sFilename), 
                                           System.IO.FileMode.Create);
        newFile.Write(myData,0, myData.Length);
        newFile.Close();

        // Check whether the file is really a JPEG by opening it
        System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort myCallBack = 
                       new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);
        Bitmap myBitmap;
        try
        {
            myBitmap = new Bitmap(Server.MapPath(sSavePath + sFilename));

            // If jpg file is a jpeg, create a thumbnail filename that is unique.
            file_append = 0;
            string sThumbFile = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(myFile.FileName)
                                                     + sThumbExtension + ".jpg";
            while (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(sSavePath + sThumbFile)))
            {
                file_append++;
                sThumbFile = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(myFile.FileName) + 
                               file_append.ToString() + sThumbExtension + ".jpg";
            }

            // Save thumbnail and output it onto the webpage
            System.Drawing.Image myThumbnail
                    = myBitmap.GetThumbnailImage(intThumbWidth, 
                                                 intThumbHeight, myCallBack, IntPtr.Zero);
            myThumbnail.Save (Server.MapPath(sSavePath + sThumbFile));
            imgPicture.ImageUrl = sSavePath + sThumbFile;

            // Displaying success information
            lblOutput.Text = "File uploaded successfully!";

            // Destroy objects
            myThumbnail.Dispose();
            myBitmap.Dispose();
        }
        catch (ArgumentException errArgument)
        {
            // The file wasn't a valid jpg file
            lblOutput.Text = "The file wasn't a valid jpg file.";
            System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath(sSavePath + sFilename));
        }
    }
}

public bool ThumbnailCallback()
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please update your title with your specific problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: the reason could be that `Anonymous` login or `IISUSRS` does not have write permission to your `images` folder.

Comment: who can i make that happen then ?

Comment: you need to change the property of the folder by right clicking on the folder, and advanced security tab - and set write access for these two users from there.

Comment: its a simple example no login issue

Comment: Have you checked the path o the imaage

Comment: Aniket is talking about folder permissions, not users having to log on to your app. There are 2 possibilities, you are either saving the file somwhere else, or your iiusr or network service users have no write permissions on the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be surprised if the line `myThumbnail.Save (Server.MapPath(sSavePath + sThumbFile));` works...

You are trying to map a file which doesn't exist yet!

Try

`myThumbnail.Save(Server.MapPath(sSavePath) + sThumbFile));`

Comment: I wonder whether you spotted the difference, in my solution I map the folder without the file name first and then I add the file name whereas you map the entire path with the file name